# Dnnfilepicker upload file button not showing for a registered user

Tags: dotnetnuke

I am building a custom DNN module which uses the DNNFilePicker control.

I would like to know why the Upload File button only shows for a SuperUser and not a registered user?

Which code must I add?

Comment: Please change your title to normal casing. It's a little obnoxious as is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we have implemented something like below for our use

```
<label class="file-upload">
                        <span><strong>Select file</strong></span>
                        <asp:FileUpload CssClass="fileuploadcss" ClientIDMode="Static" ID="POdDOc" runat="server" />
                    </label>
<style type="text/css">
.file-upload
{
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center; / Cosmetics /
    border: 1px solid #cfcfcf;
    background: #e2e2e2; / Nice if your browser can do it /
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.file-upload:hover
{
    background: #e9e9e9;
}

.file-upload.focus
{
    outline: 1px solid yellow;
}

.file-upload input
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 10pt; / Loses tab index in webkit if width is set to 0 /
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}

.file-upload strong
{
    padding-top: 5px;
    font-size: 9pt;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.file-upload span
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    display: inline-block; / Adjust button text vertical alignment /
    padding-top: 5px;
}

/ Adjust the button size /
.file-upload
{
    height: 22px;
}
.file-upload, .file-upload span
{
    width: 75px;
}

a.dellink
{
    color: #e60000;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a.dellink:hover
{
    color: #ff8040;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.customcssspan
{
    /*color: #20b5dc;*/
    color: Red;
}

.clsHidden
{
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. How can I change this code so that it can upload to the DNN Users folder?